# How to use hyperlinks to represent relationships instead of primary keys in Django REST framework

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, jsonserializer

I want to get my object index as a "resource_uri" instead id
I take the usual way I make a model , views , serializers :

```
class User(BaseModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    models.CharField()

class UserSerailizers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id','user','formatted_address')
classclass UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

when i call < my_domain/user/ > I get this response

```
{
  id:1,
  name:'toto'
 }
```

but I want to have an answer to this form:

```
{ 
'url': my_domain/user/1/
 'name': 'toto'
 }
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a hyperlink instead of a primary key in your model representations, you have to use either `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` or more generic `Serializer` along with `HyperlinkedIdentityField` and/or `HyperlinkedRelatedField`. The former is probably what you are looking for.

> The `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` class is similar to the `ModelSerializer` class except that it uses hyperlinks to represent relationships, rather than primary keys.

See Django REST framework [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#hyperlinkedmodelserializer) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

1. As already commented, you need to use the HyperlinkedModelSerializer as you've shown.
2. The lookup_field attribute should be inside the Meta class.
3. And the latest and this is a guess: You just have a ListView for your User model. In order to show the detail for the user, you need also the retrieve method. I would recommend you using the [ModelViewset](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets) so it automatically implements all methods.